# Procurar palavra em texto Php

Tags: php

Tenho um arquivo de texto com nome `teste.txt`, nele tenho o seguinte código:

```
<ID>490901</ID>
<ID>28602</ID> 
<ID>298174</ID> 
<ID>1081022</ID>
```

Quero criar um *script* para visualizar apenas a primeira linha:

```
<ID>490901</ID>
```

Arquivo em php:

```
<?php

$search = '<ID>';

$lines = file('teste.txt');
foreach($lines as $line)
{
   if(strpos($line, $search) !== false)
    echo $line;
}

?>
```

Porém meu *script* em *php* me da seguinte resultado:

```
490901 28602 298174 1081022
```

Como posso fazer para pegar apenas o `490901` ?

Comment: Você pode adicionar um `break` após o `echo` para parar a execução do `foreach` após encontrar o primeiro ID, mas deve ter maneiras melhores de se fazer isso.

Answer (score 1):

Se não houver nenhum motivo pra você percorrer todas as linhas do arquivo, igual você está fazendo, utilizando o foreach, por que não apenas printar a primeira linha usando:

```
<?php 

$search="<ID>";

$lines = file('teste.txt');
echo $lines[0]; ?>
```

Seria uma possível solução.

Agora se você realmente quer procurar pela primeira ocorrência de , procurando por todas as linhas do arquivo, basta dar um break assim que encontrar a primeira ocorrência, da seguinte maneira:

```
<?php 
$search="<ID>";

$lines = file('teste.txt');

foreach($lines as $line) {
    if (strpos($line, $search) !== false) {
        echo $line;
        break;
    }
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Isso ocorre porque todas as linhas (`$line`) possuem `<ID>` (oriundo do `$search`).

Se você deseja apenas obter o que conter o `490901` você pode utilizar:

```
$search = '490901';
```

Fazendo somente esta alteração iria apenas resultar:

```
<ID>490901</ID>
```

O `strpos()` encontra a posição da primeira ocorrência na string e se não encontrar irá retornar o `false`.

Quando você usa:

```
if(strpos($line, '<ID>') !== false){

}
```

Está dizendo para *fazer algo* sempre que houver o `<ID>`, no seu caso TODAS AS LINHAS possuem `<ID>`, por isso irá retornar todas as linhas.

---

Se você deseja SEMPRE obter a primeira linha você pode simplesmente utilizar o `[0]` que é para obter a primeiro valor da array.

```
<?php

$lines = file('teste.txt');
echo $lines[0];

?>
```

Isso irá resultar em:

```
<ID>490901</ID>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você deve colocar na varíavel $search o valor do ID que deseja procurar.

Por exemplo:

```
$search = '490901';
```

Substitui o if dentro do foreach por:

```
if($line == $search){
    echo $line; // ou $search, pois os dois são o mesmo valor
}
```

Ou então, pode deixar do jeito que está e colocar o break após o primeiro echo.

Agora me surgiu uma dúvida: o valor que você quer sempre estará na primeira linha ou valor procurado pode estar em qualquer parte do arquivo? Pois se sempre for a primeira linha, há metodos mais fáceis de se obter esse valor.